# pandas or numpy for multi column conditional averaging

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a large dataset (length = 454605) which looks like this:

```
ID  Se  Min Va
1   1   1   2
1   1   1   2
1   1   1   3
-   -   -   -
24  4   26  8
24  4   26  8
24  4   26  4
-   -   -   -
55  6   40  2
55  6   40  0
55  6   40  0

ID = participant number, ranging from 1 - 55
Se = task session, ranging from 1 - 6
Min = time counter during each task session, ranging from 1 - 40
Va = performance value for each task undertaken
```

I need to average the performance value for each minute of each session for every participant. What would be the best way to approach this, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grouping by `['Min', 'Se', 'ID']` groups "for each minute of each session for
every participant":

```
grouped = df.groupby(['Min', 'Se', 'ID'])
```

To find the average performance for each group, compute

```
grouped.mean()
```

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(2015)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(10,4)), 
                  columns=['Min', 'Se', 'ID','Va'])

grouped = df.groupby(['Min', 'Se', 'ID'])
print(grouped.mean())
```

yields

```
           Va
Min Se ID    
0   6  7    8
1   2  3    3
2   2  9    6
    3  1    2
3   8  6    9
    9  3    1
5   8  4    8
6   2  9    8
8   5  7    8
9   1  2    2
```

Comment: thanks! this seems to work. is there a way to make the values for 'ID' and 'Ses' repeat across the 1 - 40 minutes so I don't get empty cells when I export?

Comment: never mind, it seems to automatically happen when writing to csv. thanks again!